# How to render event bars/ribbons like those in google calendar or fullcalendar for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Looking for a solution on how to render event bars representing date ranges like those in gcal or the jquery fullcalendar plugin. These bars are divs that overlap multiple divs (multiple day events), and can be dragged and dropped into different divs. I will be creating a workshift calendar that is similar to http://www.rotaboard.com ...but with multiday events.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a Gantt Chart. You can download a component and see how to do it in JavaScript here: http://www.delphicsage.com/home/blog.aspx/d=542/title=How_to_Create_a_DHTML_Gantt_Chart_Control

Comment: thanks for the link. yeah, similar to a gantt chart. ill see what i can discern from the plugin in the link, but im looking more for some insight into how the bars themselves get rendered based on a date range.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You could do it with an HTML table and JS or CSS and JSS using DIV tags.